# Abstracting resource name from Rails 3 controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a bunch of resources that all have the same route, called `synced_index`. The only difference between the route in different resources is it has a different model name. For example:

```
# Page controller
def synced_index
  render :json => Page.my_func
end

# Comment controller
def synced_index
  render :json => Comment.my_func
end
```

This is a simplified example, but I basically want to abstract this into either a module or a Controller class to inherit from. So I can simply put:

```
include SyncableResource
```

In my controller class. My problem is determining the resource name. What's the best/most reliable way to do this? Right now I have:

```
self.class.to_s.delete('Controller').singularize.constantize
```

It feels a bit hacky to me though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
controller_name.classify
```

depending on the need, you can add .constantize after it

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the complexity of your app and the classes/namespaces you use. You can take a look at the gem `inherited_resources` that the do something like that https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources/blob/master/lib/inherited_resources/class_methods.rb#L312